# Slide div (left to right) from 'behind' a button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Using the last example of this guide (http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions), I am trying to get a div to toggle 'behind' a button.

Desired Result Example:
[image]
Initially the div including input fields, Button B, and Button C will be hidden. When 'Slide it' button is clicked, the div slides in FROM behind the button until a specific distance (margin) is met between the RIGHT side of the div and the 'Slide it' button.
Upon clicking the button again (and/or when 'Esc' key is pressed), the div will slide "into" the button.

Here is the script, followed by the demo:

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    var $marginRighty = $('.inner');
    $marginRighty.animate({
        marginRight: parseInt(
            $marginRighty.css('marginRight'),10) == 0 ?
                $marginRighty.outerWidth() : 0});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ishq786/xqb5a7dq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xqb5a7dq/6/

```js
$('#button1').on('click', function() {
 animateDiv();
})

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode === 27 && $('.inner').hasClass('visible')) {
  animateDiv();
 }
})

function animateDiv () {
 $('.inner').toggleClass('visible');
 $('.inner').animate({
  width: 'toggle',
 },350);
}
```

```css
.toolbar {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    background-color: skyblue;
}

#divA,
#divB {
    display: inline;
}

.inner {
    float: right;
    display: none;
 padding-right: 20px;
}

#button1 {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

input,
button {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='toolbar'>
    <div>
        <button id="button1">Slide it</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner is-hidden">
        <div id="divA">
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="password" />
        </div>
        <div id="divB">
            <button>Button B</button>
            <button>Button C</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is more along the lines of what I am looking for. Is there a way to make it look like the div is coming from the button? Or do you think this way looks more elegent?

Comment: It's personal preference. To make it slide from the button, remove the margin from the button and add it back as padding to the inner div: https://jsfiddle.net/xqb5a7dq/3/

Comment: Great! On a side note, I have another div below the toolbar. I want to display text which is always left-aligned below the left input field and remove the gap b/w the two toolbars. https://jsfiddle.net/ishq786/xqb5a7dq/8/

Comment: Thanks mark, I was already able to get the ESC key functionality working.

Comment: Also, what if I want the toggle to be split into 2 functions (if I am doing more things for each action)? Do I use the outerWidth method?

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqb5a7dq/1/).

I've solved some of your problems. I confess I'm not exactly sure how you want the outcome to look so I'll leave the tweaking to you. But two main things;

1. I have used css to get one on top of the other. I positioned the inner div 100% right, `position: relative`, and the button over the top now has its parent div set from the right with `position: absolute` so that it can overlap with no footprint. I literally moved the button lower in the HTML so I didn't have to mess about with z-index, haha.
2. I moved your Javascript into a separate function so you can call that with a keypress or however you like. This means you won't have code duplication.

Comment: Thank you. Few things: 1) The div is working differently for different page width, 2) It can be seen coming from the right side and sliding behind the button. I am wanting the div to be "eaten" by the button - to not go past the button.

Comment: You might want to post the (part of the) code from the fiddle here, to prevent links from going dead.